# Most Rails-y way to give different views of the same resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, is there a canonical way of giving different views of the same resource?

For example, a directory of people, where each person can have multiple photos, phone numbers, email addresses, etc. The people, photos and phone numbers are actually different resources with their own RESTful actions.

But when viewing people, one page might shows everyone's name and associated photos; another page is names and associated contact information, formatted for printing.

Would it be more "Rails-y" to:

- Create additional actions on the People controller besides the RESTful ones, like "index_with_contact_info"?
- Create a different controller and a different group of views?

Neither seems quite right to me, but the first seems more likely. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this situation is ripe for using nested resources.  `person/:person/photos/` could point to the photos of a person and so on.  There is a lot of material on [using nested resources](http://www.google.com/search?q=nested+resources+rails) that you might want to check out. In short,

```
  map.resources :people, :has_many => { :photos, :contacts  }, :shallow => true
```

or some variation of it in your routes and then define the `photos` and `contacts` controllers assuming availability of the person_id.

Comment: I like this. Once you realize that "people and their photos" is the same thing as "photos and their people," this is this standard solution.

Comment: Great - that looks much cleaner. I knew I was missing something. :)